# Подскажите js-библиотеку для работы с изображением как с картой

Tags: javascript

Необходимо реализовать возможность построения маршрутов по неким точкам расставленным в ручную на неком изображении-подложке.

- изображение необходимо масштабировать и перемещать с помощью мыши
- необходимо иметь возможность ставить по верх изображения маркеры, к которым можно обратится и считать их позицию по отношению к изображению-подложке
- необходимо иметь возможность соединять маркеры между собой в некую последовательность/маршрут с возможностью обратится к этой структуре для получения массива соединенных маркеров

Подскажите библиотеки которые могли бы решать подобные задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиски привели меня к [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), а для решения моей задачи [Non-geographical maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) подход из этой библиотеки.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
var bounds = [[0,0], [1000,1000]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('uqm_map_full.png', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

и так далее, согласно документации...